# ManyToMany Hibernate - estudo

Tags: java, hibernate

Estou estudando o funcionamento do hibernate e estou com algumas dúvidas....

Pessoal alguem sabe me dizer como o hibernate trabalha na questão de organizar essas informações ManyToMany?

nesse site exemplo: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

temos a tabela post com os campos ID e TITLE, temos a tabela tag também com os campos ID e TITLE e por fim a tabela ManyToMany que ligam essas informações atraves da tabela post_tag com as colunas post_id e tag_id.

Minha dúvida é como funciona para o hibernate tratar as alterações? vamos supor que hoje na table post_tag tenho post_id = 1 e tag_id =1 e  preciso mudar para post_id = 1 e tag_id = 2.
como funciona essa questão de alteração? como o hibernate entende que será para alteração? como/quanto ele vai entender quando será criação e exclusão?

Answer (score 1):

**Tornando os objetos persistentes**

As instâncias recentemente instanciadas de uma classe persistente são consideradas transientes pelo `Hibernate`. Podemos transformar uma instância transiente em persistente associando-a a uma sessão:

```
DomesticCat fritz = new DomesticCat();
fritz.setColor(Color.GINGER);
fritz.setSex('M');
fritz.setName("Fritz");
Long generatedId = (Long) sess.save(fritz);
```

**Estado dos objetos no Hibernate**

O Hibernate define e suporta os seguintes estados de objetos:

**Transient** - um objeto é transiente se ele foi instanciando usando apenas o operador new e não foi associado a uma Session do Hibernate. Ele não possui uma representação persistente no banco de dados e não lhe foi atribuído nenhum identificador. Instâncias transientes serão destruídas pelo coletor de lixo se a aplicação não mantiver sua referência. Use uma Session do Hibernate para tornar o objeto persistente (`e deixe o Hibernate gerenciar as instruções`SQL que serão necessárias para executar esta transição).

**Persistent** - uma instância persistente possui uma representação no banco de dados e um identificador. Ela pode ter sido salva ou carregada, portanto ela se encontra no escopo de uma Session. O Hibernate irá detectar qualquer mudança feita a um objeto persistente e sincronizar o seu estado com o banco de dados quando completar a unidade de trabalho. Desenvolvedores não executam instruções manuais de `UPDATE`, ou instruções de `DELETE` quando o objeto se tornar transiente.

**Detached** – uma instância desanexada é um objeto que foi persistido, mas sua Session foi fechada. A referência ao objeto continua válida, é claro, e a instância desanexada pode ser acoplada a uma nova Session no futuro, tornando-o novamente persistente (e todas as modificações sofridas). Essa característica habilita um modelo de programação para unidades de trabalho de longa execução, que requeira um tempo de espera do usuário. Podemos chamá-las de transações da aplicação, ou seja, uma unidade de trabalho do ponto de vista do usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Detecção automática de estado**

O uso e semântica do `saveOrUpdate()` parecem ser confusos para novos usuários. A princípio, enquanto você não tentar usar instâncias de uma sessão em outra nova sessão, não precisará utilizar update(), `saveOrUpdate()`, ou `merge()`. Algumas aplicações inteiras nunca precisarão utilizar estes métodos.

Geralmente, `update()` ou `saveOrUpdate()`são utilizados nos seguintes cenários:

- a aplicação carrega um objeto na primeira sessão
- o objeto é passado para a camada UI
- algumas modificações são feitas ao objeto
- o objeto é retornado à camada lógica de negócios
- a aplicação persiste estas modificações, chamando `update()` em uma
  segunda sessão.

`saveOrUpdate()` faz o seguinte:

- se o objeto já estiver persistente nesta sessão, não faça nada
- se outro objeto associado com a sessão possuir o mesmo identificador,
  jogue uma exceção
- se o objeto não tiver uma propriedade de identificador `salve-o`()
- se o identificador do objeto possuir o valor atribuído ao objeto
  recentemente instanciado, `salve-o()`
- se o objeto for versionado por um  ou , e o valor
  da propriedade da versão for o mesmo valor atribuído ao objeto
  recentemente instanciado, salve() o mesmo
- **do contrário atualize() o objeto**

**Apagando objetos persistentes**

A `Session.delete()` removerá um estado de objeto do banco de dados. É claro que seu aplicativo pode ainda reter uma referência à um objeto apagado. É melhor pensar em `delete()` como fazer uma instância persistente se tornar transiente.

```
sess.delete(cat);
```

**Funcionamento do cascade do Hibernate:**

`Cascade save-update`: É como o nome sugere, quando é feito um save ou um update na classe “Pai” as classes “Filhas” também são salvas ou atualizadas.

`Cascade Delete`: O cascade delete faz com que os filhos sejam deletados se o pai for deletado.

`Cascade delete-orphan`: Existe ainda o `delete-orphan`, quando você salva ou atualiza a classe pai, os registros filhos que estavam marcados como removidos são de fato deletados.

Com certeza este é um assunto muito importante e essencial para o desenvolvimento de projetos usando Hibernate. De uma olhada nesse links abaixo  que da própria documentação. Vai ajudar você a entender um pouco mais sobre `ciclo de vida do Hibernate`.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/pt-BR/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-loading
https://www.devmedia.com.br/cascade-hibernate-conhecendo-diferentes-tipos/28892

Comment: Obrigado pelas informações, preciso saber como o hibernate controla as informações manytomany, preciso saber como ele sabe que um objeto etá sendo alterado e/ou excluido, preciso saber como ele faz isso,não os comando do hibernate, ficarei grato se puder contribuir com isso caso saiba, obg

Comment: Se vc ler o post vai entender que ele controla o ciclo dos seus objetos de uma olhada no link e isso que ele faz.

Comment: Nesses link vejo os comando realizados para que o hibernate realizem tais funções many to many, mas não achei com o hibernate sabe se é para alterar ou excluir no caso para inserir: Stock stock = new Stock();
StockDailyRecord stockDailyRecords = new StockDailyRecord();
 
stockDailyRecords.setStock(stock);        
stock.getStockDailyRecords().add(stockDailyRecords);
 
session.save(stock);
session.save(stockDailyRecords); agora como ele sabe que deverá ser inserido e ou excluido?

Comment: Porque ele fica gerenciado o estado do seu objeto. Qualquer alteração no estado do seu objeto. Olha ciclo de vida.